# Acessing icons in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

How do I get access to icons used in Ubuntu's X Windows Start menu?

Comment: +1 to close this. serverfault should be kept for system administration issues in terms of professional systems not home desktop problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

they're all in **/usr/share/icons/**

The default theme for Gnome is Human. 
**/usr/share/icons/Human**